# Rails uninitialized constant error in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my controller directory structure

```
controllers/
.........../dashboard
...................../admin
.........................../admin_controller.rb
.........................../item_controller.rb
........../items_controller.rb
```

I expect that manager can add new item, and users can see all items.

I typed `rails g scaffold dashboard/admin/items` to quickly generate controller with namespace.

And I modified `@dashboard_admin_items = Dashboard::Admin::Item.all`

to `@dashboard_admin_items = Item.all`

**controllers/dashboard/admin/items_controller.rb**

```
class Dashboard::Admin::ItemsController < Dashboard::Admin::AdminController
  before_action :set_dashboard_admin_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /dashboard/admin/items
  def index
    @dashboard_admin_items = Item.all

  end
...
```

But it threw this error 
[image]

Also, I've put this project on [github](https://github.com/fifiteen82726/ShopCart).

### Update

**view/dashboard/admin/items/index.html.erb**

```
<tbody>
    <% @Items.each do |i| %>
      <tr>
        <th><%= i.id %></th>
        <th><%= i.name %></th>
        <th><%= i.price %></th>
        <!-- <td><%#= link_to 'Show', dashboard_admin_item %></td> -->
        <td>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_dashboard_admin_item_path(dashboard_admin_item) %>
          <%= link_to 'Destroy', dashboard_admin_item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

**controllers/dashboard/admin/items_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @Items = Item.all
end
```

Comment: cuz I have already a Model `Item`? I thought manager has to do CRUD with the same model which users can see.

Comment: hey I made it working by making the following change. Look at my answer. try that and let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you have two `item.rb` file, one under [app/model/item.rb](https://github.com/fifiteen82726/ShopCart/blob/master/app/models/item.rb) and the other under [app/models/dashboard/admin/item.rb](https://github.com/fifiteen82726/ShopCart/blob/master/app/models/dashboard/admin/item.rb). So, there is a conflict.

To use `app/model/item.rb`, use it this way: `::Item.all`.

`::Item` means you are referring to the `Item` class from the top level namespace i.e. `app/model/item.rb`.

I ran your code locally. It works fine if you change:

```
  def index
    @dashboard_admin_items = Item.all
  end
```

to:

```
  def index
    @Items = ::Item.all
  end
```

And, you are already using `@Items` in your [app/views/dashboard/admin/items/index.html.erb](https://github.com/fifiteen82726/ShopCart/blob/master/app/views/dashboard/admin/items/index.html.erb#L17)

Comment: It's weird, I have update it to what you type. But I still have the same error, I  update some part of my code on question.

Comment: see my updated answer. Do it this way: `@Items = ::Item.all`. This will work.

Comment: `::Item` means you are referring to the `Item` class from the top level namespace i.e. `app/model/item.rb`.

Comment: @CodaChang Let me know if you have any other question. If my answer solved your problem, consider accept/upvoting the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, you have been so patient and great help :)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't checked the comments. I upvote it !